# Objective C glutDisplayFunc with method

Tags: objective-c, opengl, glut

How can you use a Objective C method as an argument for glutDisplayFunc (and functions like it)? I'm quite new to ObjC, so I don't completely know how this works

In C++, you can just pass in a void, but in ObjC, I tried this:

```
    //...
    glutDisplayFunc([self display]);
    //...

-(void) display{
    glutPostRedisplay();
}
```

I've also tried static methods

```
    //...
    glutDisplayFunc([self display]);
    //...

+(void) display{
    glutPostRedisplay();
}
```

but every time I get the error "passing 'void' to parameter with incompatible type void(*)(void)".
I thought you could just pass in a void.

So, how can I make this work (it has to be a method)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> In C++, you can just pass in a void

No, you can't.

> So, how can I make this work (it has to be a method)

You can't. What you're interested in would be as something known as *closure* or *delegate*, but GLUT will just take global scope C style *callback functions*. The best thing you could to was write a global scope wrapper with a calling convention compatible to C, which then calls the method of a global scope class instance.